# John Glubb - importance and academic interest

Tags: historiography, academics

Recently I had the displeasure of discussing with someone who argued that professional soldier and amateur historian John Glubb "demonstrated" that women in public offices entail the decadence of societies.

I searched for the book, or rather pamphlet ("*The Fate of Empires*"), and, needless to say, the author can't demonstrate anything similar (though I don't doubt he effectively believed something like that).

But I got curious - what importance, if any, does academic history in Anglo-Saxon countries attribute to John Glubb as a historian (I know he is not irrelevant as a military professional)? Does anyone care? Is he cited, discussed, refuted? If so, by whom?

Comment: On my opinion, the Wikipedia article on him answers the question.

Comment: It isn't an answer, so I add it only as comment. Searching the PDF in the net and reading it, I find an almost eerie similarity to Oswald Spenglers *Der Untergang des Abendlandes* (The Decline of the West). Both claim a cycle of rise and fall, a pioneer period of warfare and empire building and at the end a decline by irreligiosity, intellectualism, materialism, greed and the search for diversions. Spengler's book received either praise or scorchers, for historians it is as far as I know light fiction.